# SAML web server not part of the domain

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

My web application is running on server(cloud) which is not part of my domain. I want to implement SAML based login to the web application with my domain(Intranet machines).

Is it allowed? If it is, any special configuration needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it allowed?

yes

> If it is, any special configuration needs to be done?

You need to implement/use a SAML Identity Provider.
In general SAML was designed as a Single Sign On technology for web-based applications without the use of cookies. You may only use so called 'front-channel' bindings (like HTTP REDIRECT and HTTP POST) to transmit the SAML messages between the SAML Service Provider and the Identity Provider if the Service Provider can not communicate with the Identity Provider.